# FMX TEdit is unable to accept the ASCII single quote on iOS

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm using Delphi 10.4 in an FMX application and, although there is no problem on Windows and Android targets, it is not possible, for the user, to enter a single quote character `'` into any TEdit field on the iOS platform...

Note that if the field is initialised by program, `'` is properly displayed.

Is there a reason for this or is this a bug ?

Comment: What does *it is not possible* mean specifically?

Comment: Works OK for me. Steps: Create a blank FMX app, put an edit on the form. Run it, set focus on the edit, use the keyboard to enter a single quote. Please provide steps where it does not work

Comment: @Ken White, I mean that when I tap on the single quote character on the virtual keyboard of the iPhone, nothing appears in the focused TEdit field.

Comment: @Mouscap please provide *exact* steps to reproduce this issue

Comment: @Dave,
Sorry for the delay. I've tried the minimal app (just a TEdit on the main form).
The problem is the same : the single quote is still invisible.
But it occurs only on an iPhone 6. Iphone 7 and upper are not impacted. I've verified this also on the full app.
I've observed the following : the single quote character is invisible but it is stored and returned in the "Text" property. When I enter a backspace, the cursor does not move but it removes the invisible quote...